# ReadItem: unknown type 64 perhaps written by later version of R

Tags: r, rdata

I was trying to load a .RData file. And got the following error:

ReadItem: unknown type 64 perhaps written by later version of R

I hit the same error on both Rstudio Server and my Local Rstudio.

Here is my session info for Rstudio Server:
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

Here is my session info for my local Rstudio:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Comment: `.Rdata` files are not cross-major-version interchangeable. You need to redo the code that created whatever data might be in that work-space image.

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting this error even when same script was saving and reading. For me it was with very large objects.

I **solved it** by making sure that the file was fully saved and close before reading.

So I changed my save code from:

```
saveRDS(my_large_object, "example.RData")
```

to this:

```
rdata_file = file("example.RData", blocking = TRUE)
saveRDS(my_large_object, file=rdata_file)
close(rdata_file)
```